# steps to clone a private repository using Google Colab

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I want to clone a private repository in Google Colab,

I opened a notebook on colab and did the following:

```
%cd "content/drive/My Drive/project"
!rm -rf /root/.ssh*
!mkdir /root/.ssh
!ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "githubname@github.com"
```

then I opened the public key by

```
 !cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.put
```

I copied the public key that is displayed after I ran the command and made a new key in my GitHub using this key.

Then I tried the following:

```
!ssh-keyscan GitHub.com >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
!chmod 644 /root/.ssh/known_hosts
!chmod 600 /root/ssh/id_rsa
!ssh -T github.com
```

then I get the following (permission denied)

```
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-d45c1532
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-d45c1532
# github.com:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-d45c1532
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.113.3' to the list of known hosts.
root@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What do I do next?

Comment: I don't think there's a particularly security enhanced way of doing this at present time. With currently available ways, you are either giving your password/token to Google Colab or storing a private key on your Google Colab session, both of which are far from ideal. Until colab has some identity integration with Github or something which may never happen.

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh -T github.com
root@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)
```

That would be expected:

- the right test would be:

  ```
  ssh -T git@github.com
  ```
- the right SSH URL to use with GitHub would be:

  ```
  git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>
  ```

You always use "`git`", not "`root`" (or your current local user) as the remote user to connect to GitHub.

Your local account remains "`root`" (it contains the public and private SSH key)

But connecting to GitHub means using the remote account `git`.

Comment: This was it for me. Adding more search phrases to make this easier to find: `ssh -T git@github.com` test succeeds "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access." but wrong `git clone` URL results in "root@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). / fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Comment: A better way to clone can be using private access tokens

Comment: @KayvanShah I agree, but this question was about cloning using an SSH URL. Tokens are used for HTTPS URLs.